# Join 2 query in different as different column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to join 2 queries within a database but place it in 2 different column

i tried union but the result are in the same column "total fulltime"

```
(SELECT (SUM(servicehours) + SUM(`teachinghours`) + SUM(`researchhours`)) as 'Total fulltime'
 FROM staff_hour sh,staff s,role r 
WHERE r.roleid =s.roleid  
AND s.staffid = sh.staffid
 AND r.roleid='2'
 AND sh.staffperiodyear = 'FY2018') 
union 
(SELECT (SUM(servicehours) + SUM(`teachinghours`) + SUM(`researchhours`)) as 'Total parttime' 
FROM staff_hour sh,staff s,role r 
WHERE r.roleid =s.roleid  
AND s.staffid = sh.staffid
 AND r.roleid='3' 
AND sh.staffperiodyear = 'FY2018')
```

How do i join it so that there are 2 different column('total fulltime' & 'total parttime') with the total sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your queries with cross join

```
select  t1.Total_fulltime
      , t2.Total_parttime
      ,  t1.Total_fulltime + t2.Total_parttime total_sum
  from  (SELECT (SUM(servicehours) + SUM(`teachinghours`) + SUM(`researchhours`)) as Total_fulltime
   FROM staff_hour sh,staff s,role r 
  WHERE r.roleid =s.roleid  
  AND s.staffid = sh.staffid
   AND r.roleid='2'
   AND sh.staffperiodyear = 'FY2018')  t1
   CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT (SUM(servicehours) + SUM(`teachinghours`) + SUM(`researchhours`)) as Total_parttime
  FROM staff_hour sh,staff s,role r 
  WHERE r.roleid =s.roleid  
  AND s.staffid = sh.staffid
   AND r.roleid='3' 
  AND sh.staffperiodyear = 'FY2018') t2
```

Comment: Thanks! what is the t1 and t2? sorry i don't have much experience

Comment: t1 and t2 are  table name alias  .. the subquery  need an alias for work as a table.. in  SQL is possible use a subquery result as  table using a proper sintax  .. as in my sample   ..hope is clear ..